# Warning: Illegal string offset 'contrasenia'

Tags: php

Estoy realizando el cambio de contraseña de mi plataforma pero tengo ese error a la hora de verificar la contraseña encriptada (`password_verify`).

El tiene que ingresar la contraseña actual y ahí es donde tengo el error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'contrasenia'

¿Qué puede ser? Gracias

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../conexion.php");

$actual=$_POST['contraA'];
$nueva1=$_POST['contraN1'];
$nueva2=$_POST['contraN2'];
$encriptar=password_hash($nueva1,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$traer="SELECT contrasenia FROM usuario WHERE usuario ='$_SESSION[correo]' ";
$buscar=$conn ->query($traer);
$fila=$buscar->fetch_assoc();
$contra=$fila['contrasenia'];
if(password_verify($actual,$contra['contrasenia'])&& $nueva1==$nueva2){

$query="UPDATE usuario
  SET contrasenia = '$encriptar' WHERE usuario='$_SESSION[correo]'";
   $actul=$conn->query($query);

    echo "funciona";


}else {
  echo"verifique la contraseña actual o que las contraseñas coincidan";
echo"$_SESSION[correo]" ;
}
  //  echo"no funciona";


 ?>
```

gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: podrías hacer un print_r($fila) cuando recuperas la contraseña para ver qué estás entregando como parámetro a la función? Suena a que estás entregando un array en vez de un valor.

Comment: si es correcto me esta dando un array 
Array ( [contrasenia] => $2y$10$mGC.bk5kaDkjbRUfhhVKsOXAv0lri6Z6.aumYDmhNIVZmsmMTv7xC )

Comment: No se si era probando pero tienes `$contra=$fila['contrasenia'];` y acá `password_verify($actual,$contra['contrasenia'])` intentas acceder a la posición del arreglo no debería ser `password_verify($actual,$contra)`? O en su defecto `password_verify($actual,$fila['contrasenia'])` sin utilizar otra variable `$contra`

Comment: disculpame no tengo mucha experiencia en php, es decir que poniendo esos 2 codigos se crea rebundancia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu prueba, en contra ya tienes `$fila['contrasenia']` en `$contra`

Debería bastar con:

```
...
$contra = $fila['contrasenia'];
if(password_verify($actual, $contra) && $nueva1==$nueva2){
...
```

Comment: si tienes razón, ese era el problema
Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda